# Difference between focus and focus-in(out)-event signals

Tags: c, gtk

What's the difference between "focus" and "focus-in(out)-event" signals in GTK+? Which one is emitted firs? How are they related to keyboard(TAB) & mouse clicks. Do they depend on each other?

I'm asking this because I want to keep track of currently focused widget within toplevel window and I **don't** want to test HAS_FOCUS flag of every widget when I need it. The widgets I'm interested of are deep inside other containers, boxes etc. What would be the best way in this situation for keeping & updating focused widget pointer?

Answer (score 3):

[gtk_window_get_focus()](https://developer-old.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-get-focus) does what you need.

The `focus-{in,out}-event` are low-level events generated by the XWindow system (or whatever in its place) and are generated first. `focus` is generated by GTK+ itsself: you can think of it as a higher level `focus-in-event`. This also means that, at least theoretically, you can have a window-less widget (that is a widget without an associated [GdkWindow](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html)) that emits `focus` but does not emit `focus-in-event`.

Comment: I want to manage focus myself. Is there a way to disable focus traveling completely? How?